# Lazy loading with Dart null-safety

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to migrate some code to Dart 2.12 with null safety enabled but having an issue finding a good way to migrate methods with lazy loaded/cached values.

Dart 2.12 will not compile the following code unless I change the return type of getValue() from `MyObject` to `MyObject?`. However `getValue()` will never return `null`.

```dart
class MyObject {
  // ...
}

MyObject? _cachedValue;

MyObject getValue() {
  if (_cachedValue == null) {
    _cachedValue = MyObject();
    // some heavy computing...
  }
  return _cachedValue;
}
```

### Update 2021-03-17

Based on the answer by [stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3983442) and the comment by [Mattia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8745788/mattia) I am now using:

```dart
class MyObject {
  // ...
}

MyObject _computeValue() {
  MyObject obj = MyObject();
  // some heavy computing...
  return obj;
}
late final MyObject cachedValue = _computeValue();
```

Comment: With nnbd to lazy initialize you can use `late final` eg. `late final cachedVaue = getValue()` and `getValue` will only be called once, when `cachedValue` is called for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ensure that `_cachedValue` will be initialized before it is read then you can use the `late` keyword which says "This will have a value eventually, and then forevermore will not be null. In the mean time it is up to me to ensure I don't access it before it has a value"

```
 late MyObject _cachedValue;
```

Accessing a `late` variable before it is initialized with a value will throw an error.

Alternatively you might consider using a placeholder value if that would be appropriate.

Lastly, you can use `!` to assert that you are sure that a value is not null. In your case this is probably the most suitable solution. In `getValue()` you would `return _cachedValue!;` instead of `return _cachedValue;`

Edit: Irn's answer is also a good one. The `??=` operator managed to slip my mind even though I use it too.

Aside from that you have a nullable value, so your getter will have to return a `MyObject?`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the null safety features of the language to get nice null safe code.

In this case, I'd rewrite `getValue` as:

```dart
MyObject getValue() => _cachedValue ??= MyObject();
```

(I'd have written it like that before null safety too, it's the idiomatic way to lazily initialize a variable which uses `null` to represent being uninitialized).